# variable that is for an email address showing up as a link

Tags: html, css, email, magento, magento-1.8

I'm creating system emails that pull variables when a customer orders. The one variable is the customers email address. I need it to stay **bold** and not turn into a link when the email comes over to our accounting department.
I have this in my css: `a{word-break: break-word; text-decoration: none; color: inherit;}` Which does work for all the other email address in the footer of the email. But since this is pulling a variable:                                                 `{{var order.getCustomerEmail()}}` I don't know how to stop this from looking like a link when accounting gets it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the variable is also pulling in styles and then is overriding- you will need access to where this is coming from to remove this unfortunately. Of course I can only guess this is the issue at this stage. Are you able to pull in a fiddle of the rendered code?

Comment: Well unfortunately come to find out, that it is not that big of a deal to them, so we're tabling it for now - as I have 30+ other emails to build... I didn't want to not respond back to you. I appreciate your time and help : )